# Python While loop stops when I have IOError

Tags: python-3.x

the below while loop stops when runs the except IOError

SO i get as output:

IP: 192.168.1.1 ,PORT: 80 ,Connection established

```
IP: 192.168.1.1 ,PORT: 22 ,Connection established
IP: 192.168.1.1 ,PORT: 22 ,Connection established
IP: 192.168.1.1 ,PORT: 22 ,Connection established
IP: 192.168.1.97 ,PORT: 22 ,Cannot Connect  (stops here)
```

Any help would be great. I can't understand why it runs the except IOError: and then stops

Thank you

```
while True:
    f = input('Type the File Name/Path:')
    if f == '': break

    try:
        with open(f, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for check in f:
                check = check.split("\t")
                HOSTNAME = check[0]
                IP = check[1]
                PORT = int(check[2])
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
                s.connect((IP, PORT))
                f = open("output.txt", "a")
                print('IP:', IP, ',' 'PORT:', PORT, ',' "Connection established", file=f)
                time.sleep(1)
                f.close()
                s.close()

    except IOError:
            f = open("output.txt", "a")
            print('IP:', IP,',' 'PORT:', PORT,',' "Cannot Connect", file=f)
            f.close()

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\n")
        print('The file {} does not exist'.format(f))
        input('Press ENTER to continue...')
        print("\n")
        break
```

Comment: Maybe it's the `f.close()` that causes some exception to be thrown?

Comment: add `continue` to the except block.

Comment: Which line exactly throws the error? Also, I think it's kind of a strange mix there of file io sometimes using `with` and sometimes not. My suggestion would be to use `with` consistently

Comment: I did add continue at the end of except IOError:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the IO Error is caused by the socket call, I think your `try/except` statement has to be changed a bit. You could try:

```py
while True:
    file = input('Type the File Name/Path:')
    if file == '':
        break
    try:
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for check in f:
                check = check.split("\t")
                HOSTNAME = check[0]
                IP = check[1]
                PORT = int(check[2])
                try:
                    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                    s.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
                    s.connect((IP, PORT))
                    s.close()
                except IOError:
                    log = open("output.txt", "a")
                    print('IP:', IP,',' 'PORT:', PORT,',' "Cannot Connect", file=log)
                    log.close()
                    continue # will go back to the beginning of the while loop
                log = open("output.txt", "a")
                print('IP:', IP, ',' 'PORT:', PORT, ',' "Connection established", file=log)
                log.close()
                time.sleep(1)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('\nThe file {} does not exist'.format(file))
        input('Press any key to continue...\n')
        break
```